# Tem como pegar o valor de uma coluna autoincrement antes que seja salva no banco de dados?

Tags: banco-de-dados, sqlite, relacionamento, auto-incremento

Eu tenho três tabelas: `preco`, `estabelecimento` e `precoXestabelecimento`. O `id` do preço é `autoincrement` e existe um relacionamento N:N entre as duas primeiras tabela, que é representado pela terceira tabela `precoXestabelecimento`.
Para que um preço seja salvo é preciso ter um estabelecimento ligado à ele, então no momento em que um preço é salvo eu preciso pegar seu ID, junto com o ID do estabelecimento e salvar na 3ª tabela. O problema é que eu não sei como pegar o ID do preço uma vez que seu valor é `autoincrement` e não foi salvo no banco de dados ainda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use algo assim (depende do seu código):

```
INSERT INTO precoXestabelecimento (precoID, ...)
    VALUES ((SELECT last_insert_rowid()), ...);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Insert/GetIncrement.sql).

O [`last_insert_rowid()`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) te dará o último ID inserido. Obviamente o `INSERT` que o gera deve vir logo antes desse `INSERT` e tudo deve estar dentro de uma [transação única](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Tem que tomar um cuidado para não usar em ambiente *multithread*. Também é importante verificar se a inserção anterior ocorreu sem problemas, se ela não ocorrer, o que será pego é um ID inserido anteriormente, que não é o que deseja. A forma de fazer isso depende de como está implementando tudo isso, da tecnologia usada. Talvez seja com um `execute()` que retorne um código indicado o sucesso, talvez lance uma exceção, talvez tenha que fazer uma *query* para conferir.

Answer (score 0):

Use last_insert_rowid(). Ele retorna o último INSERT. É importante que você use essa função imediatamente após a inserção para evitar pegar o valor errado.

Sua query ficaria apenas:

```
SELECT last_insert_rowid()
```