# Como resgatar programaticamente um ID auto incremento recém inserido no JDBC?

Tags: java, jdbc

Estou salvando um recurso para processamento demorado e devo devolver seu ID para o usuário poder consultar seu estado no futuro.

A ideia é que o usuário insira um conjunto de dados para importação (por simplicidade, assumamos que seja uma string) e que ele possa consultar se essa importação está esperando, em processamento, deu sucesso ou deu falha.

A ideia é inserir um dado na seguinte tabela:

```sql
CREATE TABLE importacao (
  id_importacao INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  data_inicio DATETIME NOT NULL,
  estado STRING NOT NULL,
  dados STRING NOT NULL
)
```

```
public int iniciarImportacao(String conjuntoDados) throws SQLException {
  try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO importacao (data_inicio, estado, dados) VALUES (DATETIME('now'), 'ESPERANDO', ?)")) {
    pstmt.setString(1, conjuntoDados);
    pstmt.executeUpdate();
    int idImportacao = // resultado na coluna id_importacao 

    jogarThreadWorkerImportacao(idImportacao);
    return idImportacao;
  }
}
```

Na pior das hipóteses eu sei que poderia fazer uma única consulta [`SELECT last_insert_rowid()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/167564/64969), mas há outra alternativa mais JDBC de se obter esse resultado?

Estou deixando sem a tag [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) porque ele é um detalhe na consulta, o foco deveria mesmo ser o uso do JDBC para tal fim.

Comment: O foco mesmo é JDBC puro, mas `JdbcTemplate` e suas variantes do Spring são bem-vindos como complemento de resposta. `MyBatis` e `Hibernate` também são bem-vindos, mas me são mais secundários ainda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não sei se isso que exatamente procura, mas você pode usar a sobrecarga do método [`Connection.prepareStatement(String sql, int autogeneratekeys)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String,%20int)) que aceita uma flag indicando como chaves auto-geradas devem ser retornadas. Passe a constante [`Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS) como flag indicando que as chaves auto-geradas devem estar disponíveis para consulta.

Para consultar a chave use o método [`Statement.getGeneratedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys()) que retornará um `Result` set contendo a chave.

```
public int iniciarImportacao(String conjuntoDados) throws SQLException {
   try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
       "INSERT INTO importacao (data_inicio, estado, dados) VALUES (DATETIME('now'), 'ESPERANDO', ?)"
      , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS)) {
   pstmt.setString(1, conjuntoDados);
   pstmt.executeUpdate();

   int idImportacao;    

   try (ResultSet keys = pstmt.getGeneratedKeys()) {
            if (keys.next()) {

                // resultado na coluna id_importacao.
                int idImportacao = keys.getInt(1));

            }
            else {
                // Caso não haja uma chave a ser retornada lança um erro.
                throw new SQLException("Nenhum id foi gerado.");
            }
    }

    jogarThreadWorkerImportacao(idImportacao);
    return idImportacao;
  }
}
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo. Vou deixar aberta um tempinho para atrair mais visitas, ainda essa semana devo aceitar sua resposta (se outra ainda mais completa não vier, haha).

Answer (score 0):

tem outro modo também que é obter por last_insert_id()..
ele não precisa ser retornado em um resultSet e pode ser passado como parametro para outro sql..

exp:

```
    sql = "INSERT INTO valorcliente (ID_CLIENTE,total) VALUES (?,?)";
    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setInt(1, vc.getID_CLIENTE());
        stmt.setDouble(2, vc.getTotal());
        stmt.execute();
//este select obtem o ultimo key gerado e fica no @id
        sql = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @id";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.execute();
//agora esse id é passado para outra tabela
        sql = "INSERT INTO parcela (ID_VALORCLIENTE,valor) VALUES (@id,?)";
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setDouble(1, p.getValor());
        stmt.execute();
     }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ValorClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        } finally {
            ConnectionFactoryMySQL.closeConnection(con, stmt, rs);
        }
```

Comment: Essa sua resposta é interessante, porém fora do escopo da pergunta. A utilização do `SELECT INTO` eu só conheço no SQL Server, sendo portanto uma solução externa ao JDBC. Eu também preciso fornecer ao cliente o `ID` gerado e mantê-lo para um processamento lento que será executado posteriormente.