# Como retornar um inteiro ao acessar um end-point?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou tentando retornar uma chave criada automaticamente em um serviço spring-boot ([esse daqui, por sinal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377513/64969)).

Tentei retornar diretamente um inteiro pelo *end-point*:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    Random r = new Random();

    @RequestMapping(path = "/teste", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    public int teste() throws SQLException {
        return r.nextInt();
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "/teste2", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
    public String teste2() throws SQLException {
        return "" + r.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Porém, ao tentar acessar `http://localhost/teste`, obtenho erro 406:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Tue Apr 23 10:32:15 GFT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Acceptable, status=406).
Could not find acceptable representation
```

E não aparece nenhum erro no console. Mas ao fazer a conversão para string, apareceu sem erro.

Entretanto, acessar `http://localhost/teste2` retorna o número correto.

Como faço para retornar um inteiro diretamente, sem precisar converter para string, no spring-boot?

Comment: Você quer retornar somente o valor (independente do tipo) ou precisa ser um int?

Comment: @FilipeL.Constante no meu mundo ideal e em meu caso específico seria só o `int`. Na pior das hipóteses eu tenho a opção de transformar em string, mas não gostaria de fazer isso explicitamente

Comment: Se tiver uma alternativa genérica também será bem-vinda

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente seu Accept request header pede um JSON e seu *end-point* não está retornando isso, por isso o status 406. A resposta com string funciona porque JSON é essencialmente uma string.

No caso do inteiro, a conversão da resposta para JSON deve ser feita de forma explicita, pois a conversão só é feita de maneira implicita quando a anotação `@ResponseBody` é usada.

Comment: Vou verificar isso, mas na minha lembrança o browser aceitava `text/plain`. Fazer pelo `curl` a requisição para ter total controle dos `headers`

Comment: Eu tentei usando a anotação `@ResponseBody` porém não obtive resposta satisfatória.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado não me atentei ao `@RestController` que já adiciona `@ResponseBody` implicitamente

Comment: Tentei apenas com `curl http://localhost/teste -i`, e continuei obtendo 406. Os `headers` que são adicionados pelo próprio curl são: `host: localhost` `user-agent: curl/7.60.0` `accept: */*`

Answer (score 0):

TEnte assim:

```
    Random r = new Random();

@RequestMapping(path = "/teste", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/plain")
public ResponseEntity<String> teste() {

    Integer numero = r.nextInt();

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(numero.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Bom, testei desta maneira e deu certo.

Comment: Assim estou transformando em string explicitamente, o que eu desejava fugir...

Comment: Eu já passei por isso em um outro projeto, vou ver se acho pra você isso.